Azure OpenAI error Error code: 400 - {'statusCode': 400, 'message': "Unable to parse and estimate tokens from incoming request
I used this API a lot in the last few days, and today it's not working, and I don't know what's wrong:
prompt = """some complex prompt (just text
"""
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model='gpt-4o-2024-05-13',
    messages=[
        {'role':'system','content':'You are a helpful assistant'},
        {'role':'user','content':[
            {"type":'text','text':prompt},
            {"type":'image_url',"image_url": {
                "url":f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64_image}",
                "detail": 'low'}}
    ]}],
    max_tokens=300,response_format={"type": "json_object"}
                
)

And I got:
BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'statusCode': 400, 'message':
"Unable to parse and estimate tokens from incoming request. Please
ensure incoming request is of one of the following types: 'Chat
Completion', 'Completion', 'Embeddings' and works with current prompt
estimation mode of 'Auto'."}`

I don't understand what's wrong. I don't changed anything and not update. any packages
i want to got response without error

What happens if you leave out the max_tokens parameter?

nothing. what is weird is that the code sometimee work and sometime got this BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'statusCode': 400, 'message': "Unable to parse and estimate tokens from incoming request. Please ensure incoming request is of one of the following types: 'Chat Completion', 'Completion', 'Embeddings' and works with current prompt estimation mode of 'Auto'."}

I have run your response code with minor additions to make it complete, and in this incarnation (below) it runs without fault. Apart from the obvious additions, the only thing I had to do to prevent code 400 errors was to include the word JSON somewhere within messages. This is necessary when you force a json_object response_format.
from openai import OpenAI
import base64

client = OpenAI(
    api_key=API_KEY
)

def encode_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        return base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')

prompt = "what is this"

base64_image = encode_image(image)
  
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model='gpt-4o-2024-05-13',
    messages=[
        {'role': 'system', 'content': 'You are a helpful assistant named json'},
        {'role': 'user', 'content': [
            {"type": 'text', 'text': prompt},
            {"type": 'image_url', "image_url": {
                "url": f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64_image}",
                "detail": 'low'}}
        ]}],
    max_tokens=300, response_format={"type": "json_object"}    
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)

Does this code work for you?

Did you try the code I suggested? Did it work for you?
